# XMLHTTP40 type not defined

Tags: vba, vb6

I'm trying to use HTTP in VB6 project

```
Dim httpCnct As XMLHTTP40
Set httpCnct = CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.4.0")
```

but when i run the code, the compiler highlight the above line and show me an error: type not defined

Do I need to add some reference and, how to use it ?

Comment: yes, you do need to [**add a reference**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=XMLHTTP40+&oq=XMLHTTP40+&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2j69i60j0l2.31280j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Why haven't you tried adding a reference and seeing for yourself?  That's probably why you got downvoted, anyway.

Comment: You can avoid adding a reference if you change `Dim httpCnct as XMLHTTP40` to `Dim httpCnct as Object` but you will lose intellisense.

Comment: Using the MSXML v4.0 library is only for legacy applications now. Either go forward to MSMXL v6.0 (so your type would be `XMLHTTP60`) or back to MSXML v3.0 (so you would use `XMLHTTP30` or its synonym `XMLHTTP`) - see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xmlteam/archive/2006/10/23/using-the-right-version-of-msxml-in-internet-explorer.aspx?Redirected=true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
C:\Users>reg query hkcr /f xmlhttp

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.XMLHTTP
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.XMLHTTP.1.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.4.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.5.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.XMLHTTP
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.XMLHTTP.4.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.XMLHTTP.5.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0

End of search: 12 match(es) found.
```

Also be aware there is a limit on how many times you can call any particular XMLHTTP object before a lockout occurs. If that happens, and it does when debugging code, just change to a different xmlhttp object

It is probably wiser to change

```
Set httpCnct = CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.4.0")
```

to (if I remember my vb6 syntax)

```
Set httpCnct = New Msxml2.XMLHTTP.4.0
```

This would give you fast early binding rather than slow late binding. Changing the Dim to object will slow things down.

Comment: Limit?  Lockout?  I have no clue what that is getting at unless it is a script kiddie using these to webscrape and a site fights back by blacklisting but is dumb enough to base things on the User Agent string instead of IP address.